# MacVim Text Randomly Disappeared

Tags: vimrc, macvim

I am using MacVim to write code in C++. I went to modify my vimrc file and accidentally clicked :w when in the file. After doing this, all the text seemed to disappear. After a while, I realized the text was still there, it just wasn't visible because for some odd reason it now was the exact same color as the background color (even though I didn't change anything). When I try to make a new file, the same thing occurs, I can't see the text (it seems to blend in with the background). I am not sure how to fix this, any ideas?

Comment: Report issue in github, i suggest.

Comment: This seems to be an application specific bug. Not directly vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seem specific to MacVim. Perhaps try to write `:color Default` to see if it make a difference

Comment: This seemed to fix the issue. I typed :color Default and nothing immediately happened. As I was reporting the issue on the MacVim GitHub page, I opened MacVim and could now see text.

Comment: I am not sure if it was really helpful, but I am glad that your problem is now solved

Comment: Thank you for the response. As a side note to this issue (still related), I realized that I had a terminal instance open simultaneously with the file I was editing in MacVim. The file I was editing in terminal was the same file I was editing in MacVim. Could that have caused an issue like this? When I closed out of the terminal instance, I believe that fixed the issue not :color Default, unless I am mistaken. Could that be possible?

Comment: I think you mean `:colorscheme default` (no caps)?

Comment: This is true. It's better to use the full name. When I write command on the fly I usually use the shorter version.